# Android Firebase filtering data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the JSON in following format on firebase:

```
"products" : {
    "-KS9-I-mz7k_4IqYMQdX" : {
      "brand" : "champion",
      "name" : "x2 style",
      "users" : {
        "oGNKfltdMsVAfjDN63QjjITGnhw1" : {
          "-KSIpwMZxesepEdNN1CW" : {
            "-KS9IQkdC0-lRYp0hzAN" : true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "-KS9-IkweDZlNf_qbbrX" : {
      "brand" : "champion",
      "name" : "wtab 709 tab",
      "users" : {
        "NKfltdMsVAfjDN63QjjITGnjdjjj" : {
         "-KSIpwMZxesepEdNN1CW" : {
            "-KS9IQkdC0-lRYp0hzAN" : true
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I need to get all the users which have this key `oGNKfltdMsVAfjDN63QjjITGnhw1`. I have tried filtering on key, value and child. But nothings works.

Comment: Since you have tried something already, can you share the code that didn't work? At the very least that will show us what technology you used, but it might also make it easier for us to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the docs for an example of iterating through a snapshot of your data:

```
myTopPostsQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // TODO: handle the post
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
});
```

**Here is that example again, but this time, I tried to use your code to better illustrate the solution for you:**

```
mDatabase.child("products").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshotLevel1) {
        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshotLevel2: dataSnapshotLevel1.getChildren()){
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshotLevel3: dataSnapshotLevel2.getChildren()){
                if(child.getKey().equals("users")){
                    for(DataSnapshot deeperData: data.getChildren()){
                        if(child.getKey().equals("oGNKfltdMsVAfjDN63QjjITGnhw1")){
                            //Here is where you do whatever you need to do now that you found your child.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
});
```